# Ribet's Level Lowering Theorwm

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-forms, galois-representations

I am reading about the modular method and I have a question about Ribet's Level Lowering Theorem.

In its simplest form, it says that if an elliptic curve $E$ of conductor $N$ has no $p$-isogenies, there exists a newform $f$ of level $N_p$ (the Artin conductor of $E$) such that the modulo $p$ Galois representation of $E$ arises from the newform $f$. My question is: is this $f$ unique?

Comment: I’d say no, but it may depend on the precise uniqueness you’re looking for. Consider $p=2$ and the newforms corresponding to the elliptic curves LMFDB 50a1, 50a2. Or $p=3$ and (apparently) the modular forms 57.2.a.c, 57.2.a.b.